# Proper implementation for multiple validation

Tags: php, design-patterns, laravel

Here's my code:

I'm trying to implement it on ServiceProvider but I don't have any luck.

```
//Contact.php
class Contact extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = array('email', 'name', 'subject', 'msg');
    public static $rules =  array(
                    'email'   => 'required|email',
                    'name'    => 'required',
                    'subject' => 'required',
                    'msg'     => 'required'
    );  
    public static function validate($input) {
            return Validator::make($input, static::$rules);
    }
}

//Registration .php
class Registration extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = array('name', 'address', 'birthdate', 'gender', 'civil_status', 'nationality', 'contact_number', 'email', 'invited');
    protected $guarded = array('id');

    public static $rules =  array(
            "name"           => "required|alpha_spaces",
            "address"        => "required",
            "contact_number" => "required|numeric",
            "email"          => "required|email|unique:registrations"
    );  
    public static function validate($input) {
            return Validator::make($input, static::$rules);
    }
}

class HomeController extends BaseController
{
    public function postContactForm()
    { 
        return Contact::validate(Input::all());
    }

    public function postRegistrationForm()
    {
        return Registration ::validate(Input::all());
    }

}
```

Is the a way that I can implement it like this?

```
$this->validate-check(Input::all());
```

I'm trying to refactor my code and also still new using laravel 4 as well.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Aldren,

I think a Service Provider is a bit overkill for this task. You can create something like a Validation Service. Let me explain:

Say you put your custom files under `app/src` and use composer to autoload the classes there.

Create an abstract `Validator` class. This way you can extend this class for every model you need to validate:

```
<?php namespace Foo\Services\Validation;

abstract class Validator {

protected $errors;

public function check($validator)
{
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->errors = $validator->messages();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public function isValidForCreation($input)
{
    $validator = \Validator::make($input, static::$insertRules);
    return $this->check($validator);
}

public function isValidForUpdate($input)
{
    $validator = \Validator::make($input, static::$updateRules);
    return $this->check($validator);
}

public function errors()
{
    return $this->errors;
}

}
```

Now, lets say you want to validate your `Contact` model input, right ? You can then create a `ContactValidator` class that extends our `Validator` abstract class:

```
<?php namespace Foo\Services\Validation;

class ContactValidator extends Validator
{
static $insertRules = [
  'name' => 'required'
];

static $updateRules = [
  'name' => 'required'
];
}
```

All right, so now we have our boilerplate done. Now lets go to `ContactsController` to implement our new `ContactValidator`.

First of all, we need to inject our validator inside the controller. IMHO the best way to do it is in the controllers constructor.

So, lets go:

```
<?php

use Foo\Services\Validation\ContactValidator as Validator;

class ContactsController extends \BaseController {

protected $validator;

function __construct(Validator $validator)
{
    $this->validator = $validator;
}
```

Great! Now we have it injected. Next, we have to make sure our `ContactValidator` is invoked when I try to store a `Contact`. Lets say your method is called `store()`.

```
    public function store()
 {

        if(!$this->validator->isValidForCreation(Input::all()))
        {
            return Redirect::back()->withErrors($this->validator->errors())->withInput();
        }
        else
        {
            //store your data here.
        }
 }
```

You can use either `$this->validator->isValidForCreation` or `$this->validator->isValidForUpdate` to check your input against the Validator Service.

I hope you can understand everything and if you have any doubts please let me know.

Cheers and good coding :D

Comment: `$errors` should be an instance of `Illuminate\Support\MessageBag` and all messages from the validators should then be added with `$bag->add('key', 'message')`.

Comment: @Marwelln this is already true, because `$validator->messages()`returns a `Illuminate\Support\MessageBag` according to `http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Validation.Validator.html`

Comment: Thanks for the input GustavoR, I get what you want to explain right here. But how can implement the $this->validator in one controller?

``

Comment: Aldren, that is exactly what I have done in my example, I implemented the validator inside my ContactsController. Didn't you get it ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input GustavoR, I get what you want to explain right here. But is it possible to implement the `$this->validator` in one controller?

```
use Foo\Services\Validation\MainValidator as Validator;

class HomeController extends BaseController
{

    protected $validator;

    public function __construct(Validator $validator)
    {
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }

    public function postContactForm()
    { 
        return ( $this->validator->isValidForCreation(Input::all()) );

    }

    public function postRegistrationForm()
    {
        return ( $this->validator->isValidForCreation(Input::all()) );
    }

}
```

Again, thanks for the input :)